# How header in php replace a header that has been sent?

Tags: php

In [php document on header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), it said if set the optional parameter replace to true, then it will replace a similar previous header.

However, if that previous header has already been sent to the browser, then such a replacement seems useless?

Below is a sample:

```
header('Cache-Control: max-age=2592000');

...
some codes
...

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0', true);
```

Comment: It doesn't, you can replace it if you set a new `header()` before you call them. After you call the first `header()` you can't replace an already sent one. Being honest, never understood why do that instead of just create the complete header when it's needed.

Comment: Why not arrange your logic so you don't output the header until you're sure what the correct value would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changes to headers are buffered up by PHP, but have to be sent before any output is sent. If you call `header()` with `$replace=true` before they're sent, the header can be replaced. But if you call `header()` after output has been sent, it has no effect (and you'll get a "Headers already sent" warning). See [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php) for how you can prevent output from being sent before you've finished sending all the headers -- this generally involves using the output buffering functions.

Comment: That does not answer the question, which is to explain the documentation and the way the function works with the specified parameter.

Comment: @Mat I've replaced the answer with an explanation of this.